# Firebase is not a constructor error(using firebase with react)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase first time and stucked on it for 2 days. looked several example like on stackoverflow, but nothing works.

my firebase version is 3.4.2.

```
     pushData(){

    var Firebase = require("firebase");
    var ref = new Firebase(" https://differentdatara.firebaseio.com");
    var usersRef = ref.child("fish1");
    usersRef.set({
        alanisawesome: {
            date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
            full_name: "Alan Turing"
        },
        gracehop: {
            date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
            full_name: "Grace Hopper"
        }
    });

}
```

When ever i am running code it gives me "Firebase is not a constructor".

also tried with componentWillMount but nothing works.
I try like this

```
     componentWillMount(){
    console.log('yesdoneit');
    var Firebase = require("firebase");
    this.FirebaseRef = new Firebase(" https://passwordsaves-11b33.firebaseio.com");
       }
```

Comment: I'm not much of a JS person (yet), but typically for something like `new <something>`, that `<something>` needs to be a type. You are using a variable. Doesn't the Firebase object instead have a method you should use?

Comment: i can't use that stuff because i am writting my code in jsx file format and working on react boiler plate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is written [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web):

> In the new SDKs, you no longer instantiate a database references via new Firebase. Instead, you will initialize the SDK via firebase.initializeApp():

**BEFORE**

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://databaseName.firebaseio.com");
```

**AFTER:**

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

Since, your firebase version is 3.4.2, you have to do it like in **after** section.

Comment: i just know my database url.. nothing else... can you help me in finding AuthSomain and apikey

Comment: I am a little busy now, I'll try to help you in some time.

Comment: hey can please you tell me, how to push the data with this version..?